# Issues connecting Installshield 2010 client to Iicensing server

Tags: installshield

Our InstallShield (IS) 2010 client on Win7 and XP are no longer able to communicate to the licensing server.

The IS clients have not connected in a while therefore it is hard to tell when it "broke".

The licensing server is a Win 2008 server running 11.11.0 FLEXNET

Our license is up to date.

The ports are open and I can telnet to the port that the licensing server (port 27000) is running on.

Ran a wireshark trace,  we can see the port connection being established on 27000 but then the windows client abruptly terminates the session.

Windows firewall on client and symantec software has been disabled.

The error from the client is “License Error 96 – InstallShield could not acquire a license because you are not entitled to use this software. You can try to reestablish the connection or exit InstallShield”

Thank You for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I ran a wireshark trace and found the following :-

1. IS Client opens connection to InstallShield License Server Configuration port.
2. IS client then opens up a second connection to a different port on the server used by Vendor Daemon: mvsn.

Solution:

1. Log onto the admin tool and valid what ports are listening for the License Server Configuration and Vendor Daemon:mvsn. (might be best to lock down the ports in the admin console otherwise they will be dynamic and change if the services are restarted)
2. Make sure you can telnet to these ports from the IS client.